# Retomar sesión SSH en Windows

Tags: windows, ssh

Hace un tiempo estoy utilizando el servidor SSH que viene incorporado en las características adicionales de Windows 10. Está correctamente configurado y funcionando bien.

Ocurre que no he podido encontrar alguna alternativa a GNU Screen que provea la siguiente funcionalidad:

> Poder retomar *(en ingles, re-attach)* un terminal de una sesión SSH pasada.

Una búsqueda exhaustiva por internet fue necesaria, pero no pude encontrar lo que busco ni acercarme a algo parecido.

#### Contexto

Estoy corriendo una serie de procesos que tardan meses en terminar, los cuales corren en un servidor con Windows. Por esto, busco una manera de re-conectar una sesión de terminal (como lo hace GNU Screen), más que mantener la sesión SHH conectada 24 horas al día es infactible desde una perspectiva de red.

Por otro lado, entiendo que puedo dejar el proceso corriendo aunque cierre la sesión agregando al final: `&`, pero existen interacciones con el programa a través de la entrada y salida estándar que no se pueden retomar después de cerrar la sesión SSH.

Answer (score 0):

para evitar que se desconecte la session deves enviar cada cierto tiempo un keepalive:

agregar al archivo de configuracion `~/.ssh/config` si no existe puedes crearlo y agregarle dentro:

```
Host *
    ServerAliveInterval 240
```

guardas y le das los permisos requridos

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config
```

o directo desde la terminal con:

```
ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=60 user@host
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Sin embargo, no es lo que busco dado que necesito poder retomar una sesión incluso habiendo cerrado la sesión SSH. Por ejemplo, en un proceso que tarda semanas es infactible mantener la sesión conectada, por esto es necesario poder re-conectar la sesión o terminal como lo hace GNU Screen. Complementaré mi pregunta para evitar futuras confusiones y gracias nuevamente por tu respuesta.

Comment: Ha intentado VNC por tunel ssh?

Comment: @Duston gracias por la idea, no conocía esta caracteristica. Investigaré al respecto.